# Pass .NET DateTime value to SAP PI xsd:Date

Tags: .net, wcf, sap-pi

I'm calling SAP Web Service from my WCF application and I need to pass a date to it.

The problem is that SAP PI does not have DateTime type, it's only Date though.

When I import SAP WSDL to my WCF application it generates a class with DateTime type. How would I pass such values to SAP PI?

Comment: What type is in the XSD - `date` or `dateTime`? If the former, odd that it's using a DateTime type in your .NET application. What is exposing the web service - is it SAP PI or a SAP ABAP system?

Comment: I'm consuming SAP PI, they are sending me a xml with XSD:Date, he also tried to change the data type to DateTime which didn't work too, I fill in the variable but the xml that SAP PI receives doesn't contain any data value, odd that XML don't even contain the TAG with data type attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, just for you guys to know it was not an issue with DateTime values but with every non nullable types (Bool, Int, DateTime, etc). The problem was on SAP PI side, we had to change the property "ocurrence" from 0 (Attribute not required) to 1 (Attribute required) of each attribute in SAP's WSDL. That's it!